# How to insert Jade markup into a DOM element in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I am trying to design a webpage where a button click will add some buttons to a `div`. If I used raw `html` then with the help of `jquery` I would have used the following code segment to have my work done.

```
$('#div-id').html('')
```

But I am using `Jade` as template engine. So I need to insert Jade block dynamically for that the button click. I couldn't find any such example on the web. Can I do it? If yes, then how?

Comment: Did you find any answers helpful?

Comment: Somehow, I got my work done (not in any of the ways hinted in the following answers), but I am not happy with the way I did it. If you are open to the discussion, I would like to discuss the problem I am facing in the comment section of your answer.

Comment: You're welcome to join me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: Are you still dissatisfied with my answer?

Comment: No waaaayyyyy. But why are you asking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on if you'd rather compile Jade in the browser or on the server. [**Documentation.**](http://jade-lang.com/api/)

## Client-side - [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SeR39Jg7IJYkgw2J8633?p=preview)

#### include jade

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/1.3.1/jade.min.js"></script>
```

#### compiling example

```
$.get('foo.jade').then(function(doc) {
  var html = jade.compile(doc)();
  $(myElem).append(html);
});
```

## Server-side

Setup a route on the server to compile jade as usual and serve it.

```
// setup route
app.get('/templates/foo', function(req, res) {
  // render foo.jade as html
  res.render('foo');
});
```

Then, use ajax from the browser to retrieve the compiled template:

```
$.get('/templates/foo').then(function(html) {
  $(myElem).append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax to retrieve the compiled html from server:

```
$.get("/path/to/partial_view/").done(function(response) {
  $("#div-id").html(response.data);
});
```

/path/to/partial_view should be a view of your jade and return html compiled by engine